# How to dynamically load a template in Angular

Tags: angular

I have created a new component, `componentB` that uses a very similar template as another component (`componentA`). Currently, when a certain `url` is accessed, the `componentA` is loaded. With the new component, I want to load a slightly different template when a different `url` is loaded.

`componentA` starts with the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reset.app-page.app-page__start',
  templateUrl: './reset.component.html',
})
```

How can I make the `templateUrl` dynamic, such that if I go to `/url/component-a-route` or `/url/component-b-route`, I can route the corresponding template. I decided to split this into two different components with a very similar template, but it would be better to reuse the template and just change a few bits.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to solve this by injecting Angular router and checking the current page url to inject a dynamic string into your template url:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-reset.app-page.app-page__start',
    template: '{{path}}/reset.component.html'
})
export class Component {
    public path: string = "";

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.path = this.router.url.indexOf('urlA') >= 0 ? 'pathA' : 'pathB';
    }
}
```

Comment: that would not work...  templateUrl must be a string. Value could not be determined statically